# Should I add const to a file descriptor?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Returned value of file descriptor always are `int` type, for example:

```c
// posix socket
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
// posix open
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
```

The returned file descriptor should not be changed (?), so I think the type of returned file descriptor should add `const`, for example:

```
const int fd = open("/dev/uio1", O_RDWR);
```

But I read a lot of sample codes and it is not the case.

So does the type of the file descriptor should be `int` not `const int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare it `const` if you like, and if it makes sense for your code.

It's true that it's not very common, probably because accidentally modifying such a variable is not a very common bug, so people don't bother to take steps to avoid it.

There's nothing inherently wrong with modifying an `int` variable that contains a file descriptor.  An example might be something like

```
int fd;
fd = open(first_file, O_RDONLY);
process_data(fd);
if (file_ended) {
    close(fd);
    fd = open(next_file, O_RDONLY);
}
process_more_data(fd);
close(fd);
```

Of course, to avoid leaking the fd, you should make sure to `close()` it before overwriting the last remaining copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for all your local variables in general, not just file descriptors. Do you mark all local variables `const` if they're never changed after initialization? The decision only affects yourself so it's up to you if you wish to add such an annotation.

You can also ask the same question for parameters. Do you mark them as `const`? `const` doesn't affect callers, only the function body, so there's no API impact if you use it or not.

Most people do not do so for run-of-the-mill variables. It's extra typing and it's usually obvious in a 5- or 10- or 20-line function whether a variable is modified or not.

For example, do you prefer this, with `str`, `fd`, and `len` marked `const`:

```
void silly(const char *const str) {
    const int fd = open("/dev/uio1", O_RDWR);
    const int len = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        write(fd, &str[i], len - i);
    }
}
```

Or this, with no extra `const`s?

```
void silly(const char *str) {
    int fd = open("/dev/uio1", O_RDWR);
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        write(fd, &str[i], len - i);
    }
}
```